# Combination of module path and class path with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-9

The Java Platform Module system allows to add dependencies both on the module path and the class path:

```
java --add-modules java.sql \
     --add-opens java.base/java.lang=javassist \
     -p mytarget/lib-direct:mytarget/cqrs.jar \
     -cp "mytarget/lib/*" \
     -m com.iluwatar.cqrs/com.iluwatar.cqrs.app.App
```

([dzone.com](https://dzone.com/articles/a-practical-guide-to-java-9-migration))

In the Gradle Guide for using the Java modules it is shown how to transform everything from the classpath into anonymous modules:

```
compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()  
    }
}
```

([guides.gradle.org](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/))

This may not be applicable when the dependencies do not comply with the JPMS restrictions like the prohibition of split packages.

I tried to enforce the usage of the class path by stating this explicitly but it didn't help:

```
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '-cp', classpath.asPath
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem can be reproduced in here: https://github.com/jmewes/jpms-gradle

The build of this project will lead to a compilation failure because the external dependencies are not included in the `module-info.java` files. Those compilation failures can be fixed by adding `require` statements with the automatic module names for the different dependencies (e.g. with the auto-assist of IntelliJ) like this:

```
module billing {
    requires spring.context;

    exports com.experimental.billing.api;
}
```

However, the compilation will fail in a later step due to the JPMS restrictions:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.transaction from both javax.transaction.api and jboss.transaction.api.1.2.spec
```

Is it possible to use the module path only for the dependencies on the internal sub-modules of the project and the class path for all external dependencies?
If yes, how can this be done with Gradle?

Comment: When I try to build the `jpms-gradle` project, I get this error: `error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist: import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;`. Is that expected? Is it part of the question? My sense is that it is not.

Comment: @MichaelEaster Yes, with this compilation error I tried to demonstrate the problem I am trying to solve. I have updated the problem description to clarify this. Please read the paragraph below the GitHub link.

Comment: AFAIK, Gradle always puts all dependencies (direct and transitive) on the module path. That's not optimal, but I don't know of a way to change that (I'm not a Gradle expert, though).